# How to choose a different header image in MS Word 2013 using a macro/button

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I'd like to create a Word stationary template with ability to cycle through different colored logos in its header. My company uses a logo in five different colors and I would like to create a single template with a button that would allow me to cycle through the different colored logos every time I create a new document from this template. Can this be done, perhaps with a little VBA?

Edit:
After working with an answer from Olle Sjögren I've come up with the following working script:

```
Option Explicit
Public imgCounter As Integer

Sub cycle_logos()

Dim I As Variant
Dim logoColors(4) As String
logoColors(0) = "logo_magenta.png"
logoColors(1) = "logo_teal.png"
logoColors(2) = "logo_orange.png"
logoColors(3) = "logo_red.png"
logoColors(4) = "logo_grayscale.png"

For Each I In logoColors
    ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange.Item(I).Visible = msoFalse
Next I

imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
If imgCounter = 5 Then imgCounter = 0
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange.Item(logoColors(imgCounter)).Visible = msoTrue

End Sub
```

It is worth mentioning how I came up with the image names, since I didn't find a way to do this from inside Word. I renamed the template extension to `zip` and unzipped it. In the extracted files I opened `word\header2.xml` (this may vary, depending on the position in the document) and edited the nodes containing the names of pictures, i.e. `<wp:docPr/>`, e.g.:

```
<wp:docPr name="Picture 1" id="1"/>
```

became:

```
<wp:docPr name="logo_magenta.png" id="1"/>
```

etc. I then replaced the XML file in the ZIP with my edited version and changed the extension back to `dotm`.

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've placed all five images in the header (since it isn't just about the color, but it was easier to explain that way). I know I can control visibility with VBA, but I don't know how to address these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, there are several ways to do this. I would suggest storing the images outside of the template, otherwise all documents based on the templates would include all logo images, even if they are not shown, making the documents bigger than they need to be. That approach makes installing the template a bit harder, since you would have to copy the images to the clients as well as the template file.

To answer your question regarding addressing the images in the header - you can address then through the correct story range object. In my example I assume that they are in the primary header. To tell the different images apart, you can use the `Name` property or the index in the `Item` collection:

```
ThisDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange.Item("Picture 1").Visible = msoTrue
ThisDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange.Item(1).Visible = msoFalse
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am aware of the bloating issue you mentioned, but it is more convenient to store all the logo images in the template, and the final product will almost always be a PDF file.

Comment: Great! Regarding your update to the question about image names: the `Name` property can be also updated in VBA, either in a macro or through the immedieate window: `ThisDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ShapeRange.Item("Picture 1").Name = "logo_magenta.png"`.